# why do I have a problem when I try to connect to a url (problem message: reset connection)

Tags: java, url, connection

I try to connect to web site. This is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlPageStr);
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But sometimes I have a message java.net.SocketException: Conection reset
What should I do?

I managed to solve the problem only when I changed my location. But why can't I fix this problem otherwise? I tried to reduce the number of requests per second, but it didn't solve my problem.